# How do you save custom settings for image quality in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

instead of going to *View > Display Performance > High Quality Image* every time

Answer (score 2):

**Many** options in InDesign can be set to a default value merely by changing the settings with *no actual InDesign document open*.

This is true for the View Menu Display performance settings as well. Just change it with no document open. This may not alter existing files, but it will alter any newly created file.

---

For clarification:

Display preferences are in 2 menu locations -- the **View Menu** and the **Object Menu**. The **View Menu** items actually do work this way... but if the `Preferences > Display Preferences` has *"Preserve Object-Level Display Settings"* checked then you either have to uncheck that item in the Display Preferences, or manually change the Object-Level settings with each import. The easiest solution is to **not** check the `Preserve Object-Level Display Settings` in the preferences.

Comment: according to [this forum](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1029617) that's one of the settings that doesn't work this way. However, it's an old thread so maybe that's changed in the newer versions.

Comment: Thanks @AshleePalka I've added clarification, which afterward viewing that Adobe thread.... is the same conclusion. The View menu will work this way. But it won't alter the object-level settings if they are set to be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change that in your preferences.

### Here's how

Start by going to `Edit>Preferences>Display Performance`

[image: Display prefs]

Then simply select `high quality` from the dropdowns, and click OK.

[image: display prefs menu]

There you go :)